# Определить какие элементы находятся в зоне видимости окна браузера

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть много однотипных элементов на странице, при прокрутке вниз мне нужно постоянно видеть какой дом элемент сейчас в зоне видимости и сохранять его. Представим ситуацию, пользователь вверху страницы, снизу много однотипных элементов типа сообщений, и мне нужно знать на каком элементе он остановился. В голову приходило решение через scroll и Intersection Observer API. Через первый способ приходило решение просто определить расстояние у каждого элемента до верха экрана и просто проверить какой из элементов находится между нижней и верхней части экрана от начала документа. А второй способ не позволяет мне отслеживать все элементы, только какую-то одну ноду.

Comment: либо можно просто вычислить высоту экрана, и проверять на каком расстояние элемент от верхней грани окна, если расстояние меньше чем высота экрана то получается что он в зоне видимости?

Comment: scroll и вычисления это "дорого" посмотри Intersection Observer как наблюдать несколько элементов [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866560/same-intersection-observer-for-multiple-html-elements)